# Javascript youtube video privacy status update api

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I tried to update youtube javascript privacy update. I checked console and saw error. I'm also not sure about youtube javascript update api function name.

here is the snippet:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.status.privacyStatus({
    id: id,
    privacyStatus : 'unlisted'
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'liveBroadcasts' of undefined
    at abc (playlist_updates.js:50)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM626 playlist_updates.html:22) .

Comment: I believe "gapi.client.youtube.status.privacyStatus"  is not correct method .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Here is the snippet:

```
 function update(id) {
    alert(id);
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.update({
        id: id,
        part: 'status',
        status: {
            privacyStatus: 'unlisted'
          }         
    });

   request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   });

}
```